# plotly 3D surface projections filled

Tags: python, numpy, plot, plotly

I'm following this guide to achieve Surface Plot With Contours with plotly (https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/).
I managed to have the 3D surface and the 3 projections on the x,y,z planes, but I cannot manage to have the countorf projection (i mean have the projection lines filled)

```py
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data = []
Z = df360_pivot.values.T
Y = df360_pivot.columns.values
X = df360_pivot.index.values

print(np.shape(X),np.shape(Y),np.shape(Z)) # printed (110,) (10,) (10, 110)
surface = go.Surface(x=X,
                     y=Y,
                     z=Z,
                     colorscale='Viridis',
                     contours=go.surface.Contours(
                         x=go.surface.contours.X(show=True,
                                                 usecolormap=True,
                                                 highlightcolor="#42f462",
                                                 project=dict(x=True)), #this is the line pjection but I cannot manage to have it filled as a surface
                         y=go.surface.contours.Y(show=True,
                                                 usecolormap=True,
                                                 highlightcolor="#42f462",
                                                 project=dict(y=True)), #this is the line pjection but I cannot manage to have it filled as a surface
                         z=go.surface.contours.Z(show=True,
                                                 usecolormap=True,
                                                 highlightcolor="#42f462",
                                                 project=dict(z=True)))) #this is the line pjection but I cannot manage to have it filled as a surface


data.append(surface)
print(len(data))

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
py.iplot(fig, filename='Parametric_plot')
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you provide some sample X,Y,Z values to test your code? Why are you appending the surface to a list?